# How does this recursion SQL script returns the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have this piece of script which is basically return the count of each interval 1 hour group. The problem is I don't know how the SQL Server engine processing behind the scene.

```
WITH dat AS (
-- sample data
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (0125, CAST('20160306 12:24:01' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 13:22:02' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 13:23:02' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 16:24:10' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 17:10:08' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 18:24:10' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 19:11:08' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 22:10:08' AS datetime))
           , (0125, CAST('20160306 23:00:00' AS datetime))
           ) t([User], TransactionTime)),
 hdrs AS (
    SELECT [User], TransactionTime= MIN(TransactionTime), rn = CAST(0 AS bigint), rn2 = CAST(0 AS bigint), hdrs = CAST(0 AS bigint)
    FROM dat
    GROUP BY [User]

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT dat.[User]
        , dat.TransactionTime
        , rn = hdrs.rn +
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hdrs.[user], hdrs.TransactionTime ORDER BY dat.TransactionTime) -
                1
        , rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hdrs.[user], hdrs.TransactionTime ORDER BY dat.TransactionTime) 
        , hdrs = hdrs.rn
    FROM dat
            JOIN hdrs ON dat.[User] = hdrs.[User] AND
                        dat.TransactionTime > DATEADD(HOUR, 1, hdrs.TransactionTime)
) SELECT * FROM hdrs;

--Lines below return final result but even the result from early step I don't know how it's worked
    --SELECT hdrs.[User], hdrs.TransactionTime, n = COUNT(*)
    --FROM hdrs JOIN dat ON rn = 0 
    --          AND dat.TransactionTime BETWEEN hdrs.TransactionTime AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1, hdrs.TransactionTime)
    --GROUP BY hdrs.[User], hdrs.TransactionTime
```

I have draw my opinion on how the way it working but I'm not sure does it really like this.
[image]

Please help me to figure out how does this work? Many thanks to you guys